# Whay doesn't Angular ng generate place component inside the module directory?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to generate a component inside a certain module (not inside app module) by using below command

```
ng generate component Abc --module myModule
```

However, the component is placed inside the app folder. Due to this app folder contains components of all modules which I think is not optimal. It would be better if I could place the components of each module inside a separate folder for each module.

Is there a specific reason for angular to place all components inside the same folder? Is there any way that I can use the ng generate to place components as I described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--module` option allows you to choose in which module the component class will be declared. It doesn't affect the location of the generated component.
As there aren't restricted ways to organize your folders, you need to do it manually, either by pointing to the right folder before launching the schematic, or including the path with the name of the component.

For example :

```
ng generate component myModule/components/Abc --module myModule
```

Comment: this works even without --module myModule

Answer (score 0):

```
ng g c my-module/Abc
```

or

```
ng g c Abc --module my-module
```

will generate component with updating **myModule**

in first case component will be created in module directory, in second - in src/app/abc/*